# Using glib in C - correct invocation of pkg-config in a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, pkg-config

I am trying to make a web server in C. I am using the [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) library which I include in my .c file with the syntax:

```
#include <glib.h>
```

To be able to use the library I have added the following two lines in my Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = 'pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0'
LDLIBS = 'pkg-config --libs glib-2.0'
```

But when I compile from the Shell I get the following error messages

```
gcc 'pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0'    httpd.c  'pkg-config --libs glib-2.0' -o httpd
gcc: error: pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0: No such file or directory
gcc: error: pkg-config --libs glib-2.0: No such file or directory
make: *** [httpd] Error 1
```

Is there anyone who knows a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have the libs installed where your compiler looks for them! And ouse correct options. At least gcc until 4.9.3 does not have such options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pkg-config` is a tool meant to print needed *CFLAGS* and *LIBS* to standard out, so I see kind of a "double error" here:

1. What you probably read was giving a parameter like `` CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` `` to make. Note the **backticks** here, they tell the shell to run a command and replace the whole construct with the output of that command (alternate syntax for shells is `$()`).
2. Even with backticks, this wouldn't work inside a *Makefile* which has different syntax from `sh`. The corresponding construct in *GNU make* is `$(shell )`, so just write `CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which make you are using, you might just want:

```
CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
LDLIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)
```